# Can a microprocessor ( specifically the ALU) be considered as an FPGA that is re-programmed by the Instruction Decoder

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, microprocessor, programmable-logic, alu

So, I have been reading about FPGAs. As I understand, they work by providing logic blocks for the programmer to link together to solve a **particular** task. Many such tasks may run in parallel; so an FPGA is more like a **multi-parallel** microcontroller. I also understand that the the ALU also has logic elements and determines what course of action to take depending on the code received from the Instruction Decoder ie multiply, add, etc.

Now, my question is, are all the logic elements in an ALU already linked into specific blocks (eg adders, multipliers, etc) or are they free to be re-linked (since there are such disciplines as ALU logic optimizations). If the latter, is an ALU (and subsequently a microprocessor- since the ALU is the heart of a microprocessor) then comparable to a **multi-recoded**  FPGA?

BONUS QUESTION: By logic, is it then a **muti-recoded multi-parallel microcontroller** ?

Answer (score 4):

No, an ALU is not in any sense an FPGA. All of the functions of an ALU are hard-wired (predetermined), and the desired result is selected by the instruction decoder.

In contrast, the logic elements of an FPGA are very simple and general-purpose, and can be configured to produce any function at all.